# Respuestas de baja calidad

Tags: discusión

Hoy me he encontrado con un usuario que en una respuesta suya había puesto un único link diciendo que ahí tenía la información que el autor de la pregunta necesitaba.

Naturalmente le he puesto en un comentario que decía (y cito literalmente):

> Hola //nombredelusuario//, sería importante que trasladases a la respuesta la parte que le puede servir a Freddy del ejemplo.

Me ha respondido que él pensaba de manera distinta y que era correcto pero aún así ha añadido código a la respuesta (he quitado mi -1) y ya está.

El problema viene que por curiosidad he mirado las 4 respuestas (su totalidad) que ha hecho en Stackoverflow en Español y las 4 eran iguales: un link diciendo que ahí tenía la información y ale.

He reportado las respuestas (y des de revisión ya han añadido comentarios) pero me pregunto 2 cosas:

1. ¿El sistema pensará que estoy abusando de un usuario por reportar todas sus respuestas? Me preocupa un poco que se piense el sistema automáticamente que lo hago como represalia pero simplemente al ver esa respuesta de baja calidad he investigado un poco cómo eran sus respuestas.
2. ¿Es mejor hacer un reporte individual por respuesta o bien hubiera sido mejor marcar una única respuesta con atención para moderación para que revisaran el caso entero?

Naturalmente el objetivo final es que este usuario sepa (¿o estoy equivocado?) que una respuesta con un link no es suficiente.

EDIT:
De sus 4 publicaciones 3 ya han sido eliminadas (la 4a no porqué no llegué a reportarla, ya que tras añadir un comentario - el de arriba - el usuario añadió información). ¿El usuario sabrá del por qué de todo esto? Desconozco si tras cerrarle 3 de sus 4 aportaciones se le ha enviado algún aviso para explicarle el por qué o simplemente se espera que al ver que se le han cerrado lo aprenda él sólo. Me preocupa que por este motivo decida dejar el sitio ya que viendo sus aportaciones, puede ser un buen usuario, si traspasa información del link a al respuesta.

P.D.: He eliminado el nombre del usuario y no he puesto links de las respuestas por mantener su privacidad, no sé si debería poner aquí su nombre/perfil/enlaces de respuestas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu actitud en este caso es la correcta. Eso tenlo en mente siempre.

> ¿El sistema pensará que estoy abusando de un usuario por reportar todas sus respuestas? Me preocupa un poco que se piense el sistema automáticamente que lo hago como represalia pero simplemente al ver esa respuesta de baja calidad he investigado un poco cómo eran sus respuestas.

No, esto no sucede. Descansa tranquilo sobre este punto.

> ¿Es mejor hacer un reporte individual por respuesta o bien hubiera sido mejor marcar una única respuesta con atención para moderación para que revisaran el caso entero?

Dichas respuestas deben ser reportadas con una bandera y los moderadores nos encargaremos de limpiar el sitio. Si encuentras tres o más publicaciones similares, te recomiendo que solo levantes una bandera en una publicación del usuario y reportes bajo la opción **se necesita la intervención de un moderador** y en el cuadro de detalle expliques el problema que has encontrado con las publicaciones del usuario. Un moderador del sitio (no soy el único) revisará la bandera y leerá el detalle, luego actuará acorde a ello.

Solo cabe resaltar que no hay que confundir una publicación que no corresponde por ejemplo un comentario publicado como respuesta vs una respuesta mala donde el autor simplemente brinda mala información o el contenido no resuelve la pregunta, los cuales los moderadores no deberíamos hacer nada al respecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación. Aún me queda una duda que ahora edito en mi pregunto inicial, básicamente, ¿el usuario se ha enterado de qué ha hecho mal?

Comment: @MiquelColl se brindan comentarios al respecto y él puede ver sus publicaciones, incluso si fueron eliminadas. Allí aparece el motivo y los comentarios que habían en la publicación. De manera que sí, tiene manera de enterarse.